# Python: append dictionary to pandas data frame row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary of following form:

```
{'2018': 21.6, '2019': 29.0, '2020': 134.8}
```

and a pandas dataframe of the following form

| Index | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Index1 | Name1 | URL1 |
| Index2 | Name2 | URL2 |
| Index3 | Name3 | URL3 |

my aim now is to append the dictionary to a fixed row, say the row with Index2. The result dataframe then should be:

| Index | Column1 | Column2 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Index1 | Name1 | URL1 |  |  |  |
| Index2 | Name2 | URL2 | 21.6 | 29.0 | 134.8 |
| Index3 | Name3 | URL3 |  |  |  |

after that I want append a second and third dictionary of same form into the rows with Index: Index1 and then Index3.

What is the best way to do that with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to insert data into your dataframe with custom order you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1': 'Name1', 'col2': 'URL1'},
                   {'col1': 'Name2', 'col2': 'URL2'},
                   {'col1': 'Name3', 'col2': 'URL3'}],
                   index=['Index1','Index2','Index3'])

d2 = {'2018': 21.6, '2019': 29.0, '2020': 134.8}
d1 = {'2018': 200, '2019': 29.0, '2020': 134.8}
d3 = {'2018': 500, '2019': 29.0, '2020': 134.8}  

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([d2,d1,d3], index=['Index2','Index1','Index3']))
print (df)
```

Output:

```
         col1  col2   2018  2019   2020
Index1  Name1  URL1  200.0  29.0  134.8
Index2  Name2  URL2   21.6  29.0  134.8
Index3  Name3  URL3  500.0  29.0  134.8
```

Answer (score 2):

I think best is first create new DataFrame by indices and dictionary and then add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
d = {'2018': 21.6, '2019': 29.0, '2020': 134.8}

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([d], index=['Index2']))
print (df)
       Column1 Column2  2018  2019   2020
Index1   Name1    URL1   NaN   NaN    NaN
Index2   Name2    URL2  21.6  29.0  134.8
Index3   Name3    URL3   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Or:

```
d = {'2018': 21.6, '2019': 29.0, '2020': 134.8}

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Index2': d}, orient='index'))
print (df)
       Column1 Column2  2018  2019   2020
Index1   Name1    URL1   NaN   NaN    NaN
Index2   Name2    URL2  21.6  29.0  134.8
Index3   Name3    URL3   NaN   NaN    NaN
```